# Node.js + AngularJS + socket.io: connect state and manually disconnect

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I use nodejs with socket.io and angularjs on client. I picked up angular-socketio example from the Internet and added `disconnect` method to It.

Socket service:

```js
angular.module('app')
  .factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var socket = io.connect();

    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {  
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          });
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      },
      disconnect: function () {
        socket.disconnect();
      },
      socket: socket
    };

  }]);
```

Controller:

```js
angular.module('app')
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', 'socket', function ($scope, socket) {

    socket.emit('register')

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Socket connected');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Socket disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('register', function (reginfo) {
        console.log('Register: %s, cname=%s', reginfo.ok, reginfo.cname);
        socket.disconnect(); // <-- this line throw Error
    });

    socket.on('last', updateSnapshot);

    socket.on('state', updateSnapshot);

    function updateSnapshot(snapshot) { ... }

}]);
```

But when I try to disconnect use this method I catch Error:

```
Error: $apply already in progress
  at Error (<anonymous>)
  at beginPhase (http://localhost:4000/scripts/vendor/angular.js:8182:15)
  at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:4000/scripts/vendor/angular.js:7984:11)
  at SocketNamespace.on (http://localhost:4000/scripts/services/socket.js:10:32)
  at SocketNamespace.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js:633:15)
  at Socket.publish (http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js:1593:19)
  at Socket.onDisconnect (http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js:1970:14)
  at Socket.disconnect (http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js:1836:12)
  at SocketNamespace.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/scripts/controllers/controller.js:38:34)
  at on (http://localhost:4000/scripts/services/socket.js:11:34)
```

And I don't understand where to dig…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Update]**

`$$phase` is an internal, private variable to Angular, and thus you should not really depend on it for things like this. Igor describes, in another answer, some suggestions for handling this which should be used instead (I hear he knows a thing or two about Angular. ;)

---

When models change and events fire from within the Angular framework, Angular can do dirty tracking as necessary and update any necessary views. When you want to interact with code *outside* of Angular, you have to wrap the necessary function calls in the `$apply` method of a scope, so that Angular knows something is happening. That's why the code reads

```
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
  callback.apply(socket, args);
});
```

and so forth. It's telling Angular, "take this code that normally wouldn't trigger Angular view updates, and treat it like it should."

The problem is when you call `$apply` when you're already in an `$apply` call. For example, the following would throw an `$apply already in progress` error:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    // some stuff
  });
});
```

Based on your stack trace, it looks like some call to `emit` (which already uses `$apply`) triggered a call to `on` (which also uses `$apply`). To fix this problem, we need to only call `$apply` if an `$apply` is not already in progress. Thankfully, there is a property on the scope called `$$phase` that can tell us if a dirty check is in progress.

We can easily build a function that takes a scope and a function to run, and then runs the function with `$apply` only if one isn't already in progress:

```
var safeApply = function(scope, fn) {
  if (scope.$$phase) {
    fn(); // digest already in progress, just run the function
  } else {
    scope.$apply(fn); // no digest in progress, run the function with $apply
  }
};
```

Now we can replace calls to

```
$rootScope.$apply(function...);
```

to

```
safeApply($rootScope, function...);
```

For example, to modify the code you have above,

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var safeApply = function(scope, fn) {
      if (scope.$$phase) {
        fn(); // digest already in progress, just run the function
      } else {
        scope.$apply(fn); // no digest in progress, run with $apply
      }
    };

    var socket = io.connect();

    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {  
          var args = arguments;
          safeApply($rootScope, function () {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          });
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          safeApply($rootScope, function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      },
      disconnect: function () {
        socket.disconnect();
      },
      socket: socket
    };

  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon! Look like a hack but It works. How do you think, should this check be in angular core?

Comment: There is a check in core--but it throws an error! I think the reason that the "safe apply" is not in core is that _usually_ there is not a good reason to have nested `$apply`s--having them is usually a sign that you have a bug somewhere. However, this case is a little more unique in that you're wrapping a third-party library that doesn't integrate with Angular by default.

Comment: There are a lot of cool libraries that doesn't integrate by default and a whole bunch of questions how to use them with Angular.

Comment: I know this is kind of a simplification of the issue, but in many cases a good way to wrap third party libraries is to put them in a directive and wrap their callbacks in `$apply`. For an example, check out this integration with a jQuery color picker I wrote for another SO question: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/x2uwQ/

Comment: A quick update: `$$phase` is an internal, private variable to Angular, and thus you should not really depend on it for things like this. Igor describes, in another answer, some suggestions for handling this which should be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

The core of the problem in this (just like in most of the other cases) is that the `on` method is called asynchronously most of the time (good!) but also synchronously in some cases (bad!).

When you call `socket.disconnect()` from your application (from within a controller which lives in the "angular context") it synchronously fires the disconnect event which then propagates into the `on` method which is designed to open the boundary into the angular context. But since you are already in the angular context, angular complains with the error you mentioned.

Since this issue is specific to the disconnect call the best options here are to

- make the disconnect asynchronous by using setTimeout or $timeout (with the invokeApply arg set to false), or
- keep an internal flag that will tell you if you are in the disconnect phase, and in that case, skip the $apply

Example code:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {

    var socket = io.connect();

    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {  
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          });
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      },
      disconnect: function () {
        $timeout(socket.disconnect, 0, false);
      },
      socket: socket
    };

  }]);
```

or

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var socket = io.connect(),
        disconnecting = false;

    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {  
          var args = arguments;
          if (!disconnecting) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
          } else {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      },
      disconnect: function () {
        disconnecting = true;
        socket.disconnect();
      },
      socket: socket
    };

  }]);
```