# socket.io and ui-router change state

Tags: node.js, socket.io, angular-ui-router

I found some question about this, but no proper solution.
I want to accomplish something looks theoretically simple:
I have 2 views (ui-router states):

- "list" that shows a list of documents with "edit" button. Clicking on the button you go to the editor.
- "editor" that shows a form for edits a single document.

If an user visits the 'editor' I want to send a message to the "list" view and disable the edit button.

*So what I'm trying to do is a simple websocket way to disable the access in write to documents that are in editing (just in frontend).*

One of the problems come when I change route. The socket stop working. The idea is open a socket connection when I join the "list" view and disconnect when I leave it to any other route (including "editor"); the same with "editor" view. Below the code, but it doesn't work.
Following this idea, when the user clicks on the edit button (leave the 'list' view to the join the 'editor' view) I have to deal with a rapid disconnection (list view)-connection(editor view) in immediate sequence (I guess I cannot be sure about the sequence of the socket events..)

**server-side**

```
var lockedList = [];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected:'+socket.id);
  socket.emit('user:get',socket.id);
  socket.emit('doc:list', lockedList);
  socket.on('disconnect', function (s) {
    console.error('a user disconnected:'+socket.id);
    lockedList = lockedList.filter(function(el) {
      return el.client !== socket.id;
    });
    socket.broadcast.emit('doc:list',lockedList);
    socket.removeAllListeners('doc:list'); //?
    socket.removeAllListeners('disconnect');
  });

  socket.on('doc:lock', function (obj) {
    console.error('doc:lock:');
    console.error(obj);
    lockedList.push(obj);
    socket.broadcast.emit('doc:list',lockedList);
  });

  socket.on('doc:unlock', function (obj) {
    console.error('doc:unlock:');
    console.error(obj);
    lockedList = lockedList.filter(function(el) {
      return el.client !== socket.id;
    });
    socket.broadcast.emit('doc:list',lockedList);
    socket.disconnect();
  });
  socket.on('doc:list', function () {
    console.log('doc:list')
    socket.broadcast.emit('doc:list',lockedList);
  });
  socket.on('doc:askList', function () {
    console.log('doc:askList')
    socket.broadcast.emit('doc:list',lockedList);
  });
  socket.on('user:disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user:disconnect')
    socket.broadcast.emit('doc:list',lockedList);
    socket.disconnect();

  });
```

the "live" array of locked documents I want to keep server-side is in the form:

```
lockedList = [
      {"client":"TourJX6zem1MpCx8AAAH","document":"580e899ca9c8621c48c0042d"}
 ]
```

keep the client socketId is necessary because I can't figure it out a better way to unlock a document an user stop editing (the user save the edits to the document or just close the browser/tab without save).

**"List" angular controller**

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('doc:askList', function () {});
});
socket.on('user:get', function (clientid) {
    console.log("(list)here your socked id: " + clientid);
});
socket.on('doc:list', function (list) {
    $scope.lockedList = list;
});
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    socket.disconnect();
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
    socket.disconnect();
});
```

**"Editor" angular controller**

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("editor_connect");
});
socket.on('user:get', function (clientid) {
    console.log("here your socked id: " + clientid);
    $scope.clientid = clientid;
    $scope.message = { client: clientid, document: $scope.model._id }; //$scope.model._id is the document id: once I have the client connection Id, I a emit doc:lock with the clientId and the documentId
    socket.emit('doc:lock', $scope.message);
});
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    socket.disconnect();
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
    socket.disconnect();
});
```

Last note: to solve the $apply issue, I use the socketio angular Service posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092745/3671995

Comment: is there something not so clear in my question?